# Oracle BI admin tool (.rpd file ) to MSBI

Tags: business-intelligence, msbi, oracle-bi

I want to convert `.RPD` file generated from Oracle BI admin tool to **MSBI**.

Comment: I haven't tried it. I'm not getting the Idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to simply convert an .RPD file to a Microsoft BI solution. An RPD file is somewhat analogous to Microsofts BI Semantic Model which you can design using SQL Server Data Tools. In other words, you would have to rebuild your Oracle BI solution using the proper Microsoft tools.

Comment: Is there a way that AMO can be used in order to convert it. Can a utility be created in order to get the output.

Comment: Sure, anything is possible if you're willing to write code but the AMO API is not going to understand how to parse and read the RPD file. It's probably going to be a lot of work. What's your use case for this?

Comment: I got the .RPD file in XML format i.e the simplest form. In msbi ssas when I try to get the xmla code (it is too large and complex). I thought of mapping it through in order to get the output but was not successful.